# Como puedo devolver un array que contenga el menor y mayor numero de otro array en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Debo realizar una función que tenga un array con números desordenados y a partir de este array formar otro que contenga el menor numero en la posición 0 y el mayor en la 1. ej:
[3,4,5,2,7,1]
debería retornar solo [1,7]

Comment: Buenas. Es algo dentro de todo simple. Podrias adjuntar lo que hayas intentado para saber donde estan tus dudas?

Comment: si soy nuevo en esto y se me complica un poco   hice lo siguiente    
 numeros.sort(function(a,b) {return a - b;});                                                                     numeros.slice(1, -1); {                                                                                 
 return numeros}
    }

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Agrega el código que has intentado hacer. Realiza el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas las reglas de la comunidad.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno tendrias que profundizar en varios conceptos antes de resolver el problema.

Te voy a dejar algunos ejemplos, pero dejo el analisis de la respuesta en ti, ya que el codigo que me compartiste tiene hasta errores de sintaxis.

```
let numeros = [3, 4, 5, 2, 7, 1];

// opcion 1
function min_max(arr) {

    let minimo = arr.reduce(function (numeroA, numeroB) {
        return (numeroA < numeroB ? numeroA : numeroB);
    });

    let maximo = arr.reduce(function (numeroA, numeroB) {
        return (numeroA > numeroB ? numeroA : numeroB);
    });

    return [minimo, maximo]

}


console.log(min_max(numeros))

// otra funcion mas parecida a lo que me compartiste podria ser:
function min_max2(arr) {
    arr.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
    return [arr[0], arr[arr.length - 1]]

}


console.log(min_max2(numeros))
```

Insito en que repases los conceptos y las funciones integradas en los arrays, por que despues van a venir desafios mucho mas complejos.

Ambos ejmeplos tienen sus ventajas y desventajas, inclus algunas podrian ni siquiera impementarse bajos ciertos requerimientos.

Comment: muchas gracias !!

Comment: Karl, agradezco mucho la voluntad de ayudar a usuarios menos expertos en la materia. Tu respuesta es técnicamente correcta, sin embargo, la voté negativamente por la siguiente razón: La pregunta es de baja calidad. No muestra esfuerzo, ni código, ni investigación. Más bien parece un enunciado en una tarea, y no se ajusta al formato del sitio. También tenemos una sección acerca de [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), y uno de sus acápites es *Contesta preguntas bien formadas*. Espero no lo tomes personal, sino más bien como una oportunidad para mejorar. Saludos

Comment: Si ya se. por eso no le explique tecnicamente que hace el codigo, y eso tarde o temprano lo va a tener que estudiar.